# Symfony doctrine raw join condition

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I use Symfony 4.1, and I need to join a table with a "complicated" condition :

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
    ->select('r, d.latitude, d.longitude')
    ->join('App\Entity\Departement', 'd', 'WITH',
        'IF (LEFT(r.postal, 2) < \'96\', LEFT(r.postal, 2), LEFT(r.postal, 3)) = d.code')
```

I got an error :

> Expected known function, got 'IF'

How can I use raw query in the join condition ?

**EDIT**

Ok, `IF` is not defined in DQL... So I use :

```
->join('App\Entity\TblDepartement', 'd', 'WITH',
   'CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING(r.postal, 0, 2) < \'96\') 
         THEN SUBSTRING(r.postal, 0, 2) 
         ELSE SUBSTRING(r.postal, 0, 3) END AS postal')
```

But the `postal` is always empty, any idea ?

Comment: Try defining `IF` in dql string functions in `config.yml` file